# redirect http to https in nginx load balancer

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, load-balancing, https, redirect

we have a setup of nginx load balancer where we configure our servers.

Now, the requirement came like all the dns that we are maintaining should be only allowed with https.

Example: tempserver.com is dns that is pointed to this public lb and which inturn will be connected with the tomcat application.

So, below is my config file.

```
upstream backend25 {
        server 10.65.74.9:80;

}

##########################################################################
server {
        listen      80 backlog=1000;
        listen      8080 backlog=1000;
############################### URL #######################################
        server_name tempserver.get.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://tempserver.get.com/$1 permanent;
}
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-tempserver.log upstream_time buffer=128k flush=1m;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error-tempserver.log;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        location / {
                proxy_redirect      off;
                proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://backend25;
        }
########################## SSL for Public only #############################
       listen 443 ssl;
    #ssl on;
        ssl_certificate    /opt/ssl_new/ssl_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /opt/ssl_new/privatekey.key;

}
```

so i have used below for redirection.

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://tempserver.get.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Now If i trigger http://tempserver.get.com it is redirecting properly to https://tempserver.get.com

This is fine. But If I pass any paramemter like http://tempserver.get.com/tempserver

it is accepting http connection and redirection is not happening.

So, what can be done here? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred pattern to do HTTP to HTTPS redirect is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

You need to remove `listen 80;` and the `if` statement from your current configuration when using this.